# ¿La sentencia break interrumpe la ejecución del programa o del bloque?

Tags: c++

En el siguiente código el programa termina cuando el usuario entra `'|'`, y, por tanto la función `keep_window_open()` no llega a ejecutarse a pesar de estar fuera del scope del bucle `while`... o mejor dicho no hace lo que debería hacer

```
//
// Drill CHp 4 pg 101, Programming: Principles and Practice using C++
// 1. Write a program that consists of a while-loop that (each time
// around the loop) reads two ints and then prints them. Exit the  
// program when a terminating '|' is entered.
//
// Code by JAME
//

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }

int main()
{
    int x{ 0 }, y{ 0 };
    while (cin >> x >> y) {
        if (x != '|' && y != '|')
            cout << x << '\t' << y << endl;
        else
            break;
    }
    keep_window_open();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` es una palabra clave que permite abandonar el bucle en el que se encuentra el punto de ejecución. `break` no es capaz de abandonar la función actual ni de saltar más allá del final del bucle. Por supuesto no se puede usar `break` fuera de un bucle local (dentro de la misma función):

```
void func()
{ break; } // Error. break no está dentro de un bucle

int main()
{
  while(1)
  { func(); }
}
```

Si utilizas un depurador de código o editas la función para que muestre un mensaje verás como realmente si que se ejecuta:

```
inline void keep_window_open() { cout << "bingo"; char ch; cin >> ch; }
```

Entonces. ¿Qué sucede? El problema que te estas encontrando se produce porque la lectura:

```
cin >> x >> y
```

No está eliminando el salto de línea que se encuentra después de leer `y`. En consecuencia, cuando la función `inline` trata de pausar la ejecución hasta que el usuario pulse una tecla se encuentra con que ya existe un carácter en el buffet de entrada... Se lee dicho carácter y la espera se da por finalizada.

La solución pasa por limpiar el buffer de entrada antes de proceder a realizar la espera:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

Esta instrucción descartará todo el contenido del buffer de entrada hasta que se encuentre un salto de línea (que también será descartado).

Answer (score 3):

Según el [estándar C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (la traducción y el resaltado es mío):

> #### § 6.6.1 la instrucción `break`
>
> 1. La instrucción `break` debe aparecer sólo en una instrucción de iteración o una instrucción `switch` y **causará la finalización de la instrucción de iteración más pequeña y anidada** o la instrucción `switch`; el control pasa a la instrucción posterior a la instrucción finalizada, si hay alguna.
>
> #### § 6.6.2 la instrucción `continue`
>
> 1. La instrucción `continue` debe aparecer sólo en una instrucción de iteración y provocará que el control salte hasta la sección de continuación del bucle de la instrucción de iteración más pequeña, esto es, al final del bucle. Concretamente, en cada una de las instrucciones:
>
>    ```
>    while (foo) {            do {            for (; ;) {
>     {                         {                {
>       // ...                    // ...           // ...
>     }                         }                }
>     contin: ;                contin: ;       contin: ;
>    }                        }               }
>    ```
>
> Una instrucción `continue` fuera de una instrucción de iteración es equivalente a `goto contin`.

Suele ser difícil de interpretar el estándar, y al traducir puedo haber cometido errores que modifiquen el significado, pero viene a decir:

- Una instrucción `break` sólo *rompe* el bucle en que se encuentra.